# How to user FirebaseIndex with random child IDs

Tags: firebase, angularfire

I have this nodes, the ref childs have randomID.

```
master: {
 123: {
  text: "hello world"
 },

 456: {
  text: "hello world 2"
 }
}

ref: {
 abc: {
  123: 1,
  456: 1
 },

 efg: {
  456: 1
 }
}
```

I want to loop the `ref` and it `refToMaster`. How to query using FirebaseIndex ?

`new FirebaseIndex(ref.child(STUCK_HERE), master);`

**UPDATE**

I updated my node structure to what hiattp and kato mentioned.

Sorry for my unclear question, I re-edit this. Actually I want to retrieve both `ref.abc` and `ref.efg` and also retrieve their related master data which are `123` and `456`

Below is what I have tried.

```
angularFireCollection(ref, function(s) {
 s.forEach(function(cs){
  //cs.name() - So I can get abc and efg and put in FirebaseIndex
  var index = new FirebaseIndex(ref.child(cs.name()), master);
  $scope.foos = angularFireCollection(index);
  //I stuck here, must be something wrong.
 })
})
```

Comment: Won't `$scope.foos` be overwritten for each object in `ref`? Otherwise it looks like you already have what you want within that `forEach` call: The `ref` object in the `cs` var and the related `master` objects in `$scope.foos`.

Comment: @hiattp I come back to issue. you are right, will overwritten. Any idea how to fix this?  is that i need to use closure? but how?

Comment: I'd need an understanding of your high-level goal, it's unclear why you've gone down this route in the first place. You might not even want to use angularFireCollection. But in general if you want to add to instead of overwrite a collection, just append the new data.

Comment: @hiattp I need `angularFireCollection` because I need three way data-binding. The problem is when I loop using `ng-repeat` in view. It only return the last value. is this the closure question?

Comment: I don't think so. Jump in [stackchat](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stack-chat/ceoaibfheddfhkpaegnnlppghfjoalpi) and I might be able to help more. We've wandered away from your original question.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, `abc` and `efg` should be lists of keys (required as the first parameter in `FirebaseIndex`). So instead of `refToMaster: "key"` the format should be `"key":1`, where the 1 is just a placeholder. Like this:

```
ref: {
  abc: {
   "123":1,
   "456":1
  },
  efg: {
   "456":1
  }
}
```

Now `new FirebaseIndex(ref.child('abc'), master)` will give you both the `123` and the `456` objects in `master`, while `new FirebaseIndex(ref.child('efg'), master)` will just give you the `456` object.

Comment: I updated my question. I want to loop ref and their related master data.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. You'll have to explain your end goal a bit more specifically or use example data that is less abstract. It's unclear how the notion of "looping" would apply to `FirebaseIndex`.

Answer (score 0):

@hiattp has noted the standard format for FirebaseIndex. This is the intended use case.

You can also pass a function into the `dataRef` for FirebaseIndex, which would allow you to deal with more sophisticated paths:

```
new FirebaseIndex( 
   new Firebase('URL/index'), 
   function(pathName) {
      return new Firebase('URL/data/'+pathName+'/widget');
   }
);
```

But as your data structure stands in the question, the keys `abc` and `efg` are completely arbitrary--not linked in any way to your `master` data, so I don't see what your function could do other than contain a complete map from master keys to ref paths.